# What are total number of PageEvents in asp.net lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What are total number of PageEvents in asp.net lifecycle ?
I found it disputable because at some places it is 9, some has more than 20 (e.g at msdn and codeproject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stick to msdn for asp.net documentation. You can count how many msdn claim, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: but if you see at the bottom of the page there are like 30+ of them :/

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following link, It will clearly explain

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like they have shown, the first place you want to look for asp.net and any .Net products, is MSDN. [Here](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1512/aspnet-page-life-cycle-events/) is a nice article from the ASP.NET wiki in the ASP.NET site.